# Why is ActiveRecord objects.size returning the wrong number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord between a School object and a User object that is joined through a `has_many :through, :uniq => true` relationship.

In the school class, I have a specific method to query for students:

```
def students
  self.users.where(educations: {end_date: nil})
end
```

This appears to correctly give me unique users only (no-duplicates), but the strange thing is the `school.students.size` gives me a count that includes duplicate records! However if I look at the enumerable returned by school.students, it only shows unique records.

I've tried adding a #uniq to the end of the where query. This does not seem to fix the problem. So far my only solution is to use `school.students.compact.size` but this can't be right.

By the way, `school.users.size` gives me an accurate count.

Comment: could you please share a gist as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `count` on ActiveRecord::Relation objects, as that lets it do a count query on the database.  Calling `size` causes to fetch all of the objects from the database, create an Array, and then call `size` on that.  This probably won't fix your issue though.

Does creating another association make a difference?

```
has_many :students, class_name: User, through: SchoolUsers(?), conditions: {educations: {end_date: nil}}
```

Comment: I'll try that. #length works properly but #count does not. I'm guessing that #size & #count are not counting the size of the array but rather doing a count query on the db.